# Prove that there exists a four colored intersection in a four colored $100×100$ grid

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle, invariance

> A $100×100$ grid is colored with four colors. There are exactly 25 blocks of each color in every row and column. Prove that there exists an intersection between two rows and columns such that all four intersecting blocks have different colors.

I am trying to prove this using invariance. But I don't know how to proceed. I also don't know if this is the correct approach so any ideas is appreciated:)

Comment: Do the rows (columns) need to be adjacent? [I assume not since that isn't said...]

Comment: I think a proof based on the pigeonhole principle is much more likely to be productive.  Each column has $1200$ pairs of rows with the blocks of the same color.

Comment: I assume they don't@coffeemath

Comment: could you explain more? (This is not a homework assignment.)@Robert Shore

Comment: @coffeemath: I assume that they do have to be adjacent, and we’re looking for an intersection of a row boundary and a column boundary that is a corner of one square of each color.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott In one of the comments OP says they aren't assumed adjacent.

Comment: @coffeemath: No, she says that she **assumes** that they don’t have to be adjacent. And she may be right: that looks like an easier problem than the one that I got from the wording. To be sure: you think that it’s asking us to show that there are rows $r_1,r_2$ and columns $c_1,c_2$ such that the four squares that are intersection of $r_i$ and $c_j$, $i,j\in\{1,2\}$, are all different colors. I read it as asking us to show that there’s a ‘Four Corners’ point where $4$ squares of different colors have a common corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that there are $\binom{4}{2} \cdot 25^2$ pairs of different colors on each row, so there are $100 \cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot 25^2$ pairs of different colors which are on the same row in total. Now, notice that $100 \cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot 25^2 > 75 \cdot \binom{100}{2}$. So, by the generalized pigeonhole principle, there are two columns with $>75$ pairs of different colors which are on the same row. Say there are 76 pairs of different colors which are on the same row. Say the names of the colors are from the set $\{0,1,2,3\}$. Now, if the claim is not true, then either $\{0,1\}$, $\{0,2\}$, $\{0,3\}$ or $\{0,1\}$, $\{0,2\}$, $\{1,2\}$ are the possible pairs we can use to cover these $2$ columns (WLOG). The first case is clearly impossible since we have a limit of $25$ for each color, and the second case is impossible since $3$ colors are not enough to cover a total of $76 \cdot 2=152$ blocks. So the claim is true.

**Edit:** If you cannot understand what I mean by "pairs of different colors that are on the same row", see the comments below from @Mike.

Comment: Very nice. But it did take me a few times reading this to see the idea. At first I didnt know what you meant by "pairs of different colors that are on the same row". Let $a_{ij}$ be the color of the entry on column $i$ and row $j$ of the grid...

Comment: You show that there are two integers $i_1$ and $i_2$ that satisfy the following: there is a set $J$ at least 76 integers $j$ such that $a_{i_1j} \not = a_{i_2j}$. And then you use this to show that given $i_1$ and  $i_2$, then are 2 integers $j_1$ and $j_2$ in $J$ such that $a_{i_1j_1}, a_{i_1j_2}, a_{i_2j_1}, a_{i_2j_2}$ are all distinct from each other. And so then the intersections of columns $j_1$ and $j_2$ with rows $i_1$ and $i_2$ solve the problem.

Comment: @Mike You are right I wrote it in a kind of confusing way.